# form is not getting rendered in django

Tags: python, html, django

the model class is :

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=120)
   address=models.CharField(max_length=120)
   trek=models.CharField(max_length=120)
   transid=models.CharField(max_length=20 ,default="")
```

the form class is

```
class formm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Product
    fields=('name','address','trek','transid')
    #fields="__all__"
    # exclude=['title']
```

the form part of html is

```
<div class="jumbotron">

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}



  {{ form.as_p }}



   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>

   </form>
   </div>
```

the function in view is

```
def book(request):

    form=formm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

           form.save()
           return redirect('/')

        else:
              form=formm()

    return render(request, 'trek/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

the html rendered is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">

 <form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>

  </form>
   </div>
  </body>
  </head>

  </html>
```

The form is not getting rendered .Only the submit button is getting shown.
 there are no identation errors.

all the imports are done properly.I have done this type of stuff before also but this never occured.

Comment: This is not a direct answer brcause I don't see any problems. But, you should rename the "formm" to something else, it's a bit hard to read. Also in your code, is "class Meta" within "formm" indented? Because in your question it is not.

Comment: yes it is indented

Comment: @Vipulsaklani: the code in your question is *not* properly indented.

Comment: Can you post your `import`'s in your `view` as well?

Comment: Please post the final rendered `html` too.

Comment: added the simplified html

Answer (score 0):

Does your return render have the correct template (trek/contact.html)? You say your form is in `<div class="jumbotron">` but it's in `<div class="container">` in the html rendered. Also, your `<body>` tag being rendered inside the `<head>` tag, I'm not sure if that would cause issues in some browsers.